# How to write a line of code to save a plot as a png?

Tags: r

I'm trying to save a plot I made and tried using this code:

```
png(filename = "file_name.png",
    width = 500, height = 500)
```

I don't get any error message but the plot isn't getting saved, how can I get it to save to my files list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using base R, first use your `png` code, then below it put the code for the plot (i.e. `plot(...)`, then below that put `dev.off()` and see if that works by checking your directory. For example:

```
png(filename = "file_name.png",
    width = 500, height = 500)

plot(1:100, 1:100)

dev.off()
```

As opposed to base R, if you are using `ggplot2` then you run the plot first, then run the `ggsave` command:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

ggsave(filename = "file_name_ggplt.png", width = 500, height = 500, units = "px")
```